# How to create MS Excel formula for the following

Tags: excel-formula

How to create excel formula for this:

- IF B2 & C2 ARE SAME , SHOW 1 IN D2
- IF B2 & C2 ARE DIFFERENT, SHOW -0.33 IN D2
- IF C2 IS BLANK, SHOW 0 IN D2

Answer (score 1):

Nested IF:

```
=IF(C2="",0,IF(B2=C2,1,-0.33))
```